# Notepad ++ find and replace issue

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have had some luck with notepad ++ solving some complex find and replace a lot of similar text in around 8000 documents, but not this particular one:

In a text file I will have a lot of lines that say:

```
ABKNUMBER001=30422
```

and I need to change this to:

```
ABKNUMBER001=6543230422
```

I need the find and replace to be sure it's only replacing the line if ONLY 5 characters beginning with 3 exist after the '='

For example, this line below would not need to be changed:

```
ABKNUMBER001=304221
```

In fact, what I really need is to find anything that matches the lines below where xxx can be any digits 0-9 and yyyy can also be any digits 0-9 (but limited to just 4 digits), as follows:

```
ABKNUMBERxxx=3yyyy
```

My list will have entries ABKNUMBER001, 002...999 in each text file and I want to replace any of those 999 entries per text file that have a match for `3yyyy` with `654323yyyy` - make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want to replace any of those 999 entries per text file that have a match for 3yyyy with 654323yyyy

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `^(ABKNUMBER[0-9][0-9][0-9]=)(3[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])$` or
- Set "Find what" to `^(ABKNUMBER[0-9]{3}=)(3[0-9]{4})$`
- Set "Replace with" to `\1654\2`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
ABKNUMBER001=30422
ABKNUMBER002=40422
ABKNUMBER004=50422
ABKNUMBER005=60422
ABKNUMBER001=304221
```

**After**:

```
ABKNUMBER001=65430422
ABKNUMBER002=40422
ABKNUMBER004=50422
ABKNUMBER005=60422
ABKNUMBER001=304221
```

---

#### Further reading

- [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation ? | Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: I am struggling to get matches. I know in my folder I have many files that should match (see a direct copy of the first part of one text file but it is not finding them in notepad++                                                     English/Metric Units=
ABKNAME001=Amy
ABKNUMBER001=30566
ABKTYPE001=1
ABKNAME002=Cardio
ABKNUMBER002=21291
ABKTYPE002=0

Comment: @Cheddar Is all that data on separate lines?

Comment: my data is interlaced with a few other non-relevant bits of data. If I use np++ to search just that a single file I get no matches...curious.

Comment: English/Metric Units=
ABKNAME001=Amy
ABKNUMBER001=30566
ABKTYPE001=1
ABKNAME002=Cardio
ABKNUMBER002=21291
ABKTYPE002=0

Comment: Try replacing `$` with `[ ]*$`. It works for me even with trailing spaces.

Comment: I got one replace with your data (line 3).

Comment: Interestingly if I remove the $ altogether it works. I also now get hits when I use np++ Find in Files I know get many many hits - thank you!  Any thoughts on why the $ didn't work?

Comment: @Cheddar You have trailing spaces? See my comment above.

Comment: The []*$ didn't work for me either - got what I needed though with a minor tweak and thank you - awesome help :)

Answer (score 2):

Notepad++ does Perl regular expressions. This has, in particular, repetition operators:

```
ABKNUMBER[0-9]{3}=3[0-9]{4}$
```

I replace your xxx with `[0-9]{3}` to request exactly 3 digits and yyyy with `[0-9]{4}` to request exactly 4 digits. In addition I terminate with `$` to match the end of the line. You may want to insert a `[ ]*` in front of the `$`, in case you are not sure that there are no stray space at the end of the lines.

This answer is based on what I know of regular expressions. I have no np++ at hand to test this, so please test first.

Comment: I am struggling to get any hits in np++ when finding in files. An excerpt from a known matched file below is not being pulled up.                             English/Metric Units=
1ABKNAME001=Amy
ABKNUMBER001=30566
ABKTYPE001=1
ABKNAME002=Cardio
ABKNUMBER002=21291
ABKTYPE002=0

Comment: Thank you - with your and @DavidPostill help, this is solved.